# Efficient computation of a (truncated) distribution's parameters given the moments (and back)

Tags: normal-distribution, algorithms

I have a probability distribution of the form:

$$p(\vec x) = Z^{-1} \delta\left(\sum_i x_i\right)\exp \left[ \sum_i (\phi_i x_i + \psi_i x_i^2) \right]$$

for $\vec a \le \vec x \le \vec b$, and $p(\vec x)=0$ otherwise, where $Z$ is a normalization constant, $\phi_i, \psi_i$ are constants, $\delta( )$ is the Dirac delta function, and $\vec a \le \vec b$ (vector inequalities are interpreted component-wise).

My problem is as follows. I need efficient computational methods to calculate $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$ given the single-variable first and second moments,

$$\langle x_i \rangle=\int p(\vec x)x_i d\vec x$$
$$\langle x_i^2 \rangle=\int p(\vec x)x_i^2 d\vec x$$

And back. Given $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$, calculate the moments $\langle x_i \rangle$ and $\langle x_i^2 \rangle$.

Comment: Why should the known first two moments provide a good approximation of the pdf (and thus of its parameters)?

Comment: @wolfies Just count the equations. There are $2n$ parameters $\phi_i,\psi_i$ (where $n$ is the number of components of $\vec x$), and there are $2n$ moments $\langle x_i\rangle$, $\langle x_i^2\rangle$. I expect that one set of variables determines the other. Don't you agree?